# C# To find exact string type element from Enumerable Object Array having Multiple elements in

Tags: c#, .net, object, iteration, ienumerable

I have a complex enumerable object array in C#, where elements can be of multiple types.
Where those are type of specific classes, I can apply OfType(). But there are multiple string type elements, and I cannot rely on their order sequence.

e.g. I can rely on the ApplicationApplicationState object element as:

```
dto.ApplicationState = application?.Items?.OfType<ApplicationApplicationState>()?.FirstOrDefault().ApplicationState?.Items
                ?.FirstOrDefault()?.To<multilingualStringField>()?.value?
                .FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
```

Can I apply some method, to get my desired value.

However, there are two elements in the base array, Items and ItemsElementName, which I thought primarily can come handy, where 4th Item element type name, provided in ItemElementName. Not sure if that is helpful.

Below is an overview of the Enumerable Object array from VS 2019 debugger.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand what your "desired value" is. Do you want to get the n-th element where n in the index of "BillRate" in ItemsElementName?

Comment: actually no, I can't rely on n-th element, as the order depends on availability, it can vary. I need a method which I can apply to find my "BillRate" value from Items array. If somehow I can get the position of "BillRate" from ItemElementName array, and then I can access the ElementAtOrDefault. Thanks

Comment: You can get the index by `Array.IndexOf(ItemsElementName, "BillRate")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `Enumerable.Zip`. It allows you to combine `Items` and `ItemsElementName`.

```
var valuesByName = Items
  .Zip(ItemElementName, (i, n) => new KeyValuePair<string,object>(n.ToString(), i)))
  .Where(kv => kv.Value is string)
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (string)x.Value);
```

Now you can identify which value belongs to which field: `valuesByName["BillRate"]`

You can easily replace the string key by a more specific type.